# React: can I change a state (useState) without causing a repaint, so that I can see a css transition?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-in-js

I have different "cards" that on click `onClick` I want their `margin-left` property to be modified

To do that I use `useState`, for which I have only one state that is an object that stores the states for all the cards

The below example code shows the problem, but a simplified version that doesn't have a component `<Type>` and that uses a simple `elements` array works as expected

So, if I need to use a structure like the one below, how could I keep the transition effect?

Example code

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shadow-2v16s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export default function App() {
  const [userTap, setUserTap] = useState({});
  const elements1 = [...Array(5)];
  const elements2 = [...Array(3)];

  const Type = ({ list }) =>
    list.map((el, i) => (
      <Ingredient
        key={"draggable" + i}
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          userTap[i] = userTap[i] ? 0 : 1;
          setUserTap({ ...userTap }); // create a new ref to provoke the rerender
          return;
        }}
        userTap={userTap[i]}
      >
        <div>item</div>
      </Ingredient>
    ));

  return (
    <>
      <Type list={elements1} />
      <Type list={elements2} />
    </>
  );
}

const Ingredient = styled.li`
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: ${props => (props.userTap ? "100px" : "15px")};
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
`;
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve]. Otherwise, is a key used on the `Ingredient` items?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that your `Ingredient` component should maintain its own state, instead of this parent component.

Comment: I've just made an example and ... it does work there https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shadow-2v16s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark so unfortunate, in my code definetively doesn't work

Comment: @EmileBergeron I've included a working example that reflects the problem I've tried to describe

Comment: @larz I've tried your suggestion, and it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing needed to be done, as @larz suggested in the comments, is to move the `useState` to the last component, as shown below

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hawking-5p81d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export default function App() {
  const elements1 = [...Array(5)];
  const elements2 = [...Array(3)];

  const Type = ({ list, type }) => {
    const [userTap, setUserTap] = useState({});
    return list.map((el, i) => (
      <Ingredient
        key={"draggable" + i}
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          userTap[type + i] = userTap[type + i] ? 0 : 1;
          setUserTap({ ...userTap }); // create a new ref to provoke the rerender
          return;
        }}
        userTap={userTap[type + i]}
      >
        <div>item</div>
      </Ingredient>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Type list={elements1} type="one" />
      <Type list={elements2} type="two" />
    </>
  );
}

const Ingredient = styled.li`
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: ${props => (props.userTap ? "100px" : "15px")};
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
`;
```